# VueResource res.render() don't do anything

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, vuejs2

I am actually trying to render a special html pages when the users are logging in.
I am using VueJs and an Express server.

When the user enter his username and pass I launch an ajax call via VueResource.

```
this.$http.post('/dashboard', JSON.stringify(this.user)).then((response) => {
              if (!response.body) {
                  let message = "blabla";
                  this.$emit('showAlert', [message])
              }
          }, (response) => {
              alert("don't work")
          });
```

And in my Express router I've this :

```
router.post('/dashboard', function(req, res) {

var user = req.body;

loginController(user.username, user.password).then(function(utilisateurReconnu) {
  if(utilisateurReconnu){
    res.render('../views/dashboard.html', function(err,html){
      if (err) throw err;

      res.send(html);
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.send(utilisateurReconnu);
  }

});
```

The loginController function just send true when the user is recognized in the db.
I just made a console.log(html), and I actually see my page but my res.render don't do anything and I don't understand why :(

Comment: remove the callback while rendering the page

Comment: You mean like this :

loginController(user.username, user.password).then(function(utilisateurReconnu) {
      if(utilisateurReconnu){
        res.render('../views/dashboard.html');
      } else {
        res.send(utilisateurReconnu);
      }
    });

If yes, already tried :(

Comment: no i mean app.redner instead of res.render

Comment: That don't work :(

Comment: What are you trying to do after the user logs in? It is strange that you render the template inside a POST request.

Comment: I am trying to render the main website after the users logged in.
Even if I do a GET request, that's not working :(

Comment: Normally you don't render the page and return it in response to a post request. What you should do is return some kind of token for the user to store in the browser. (JWT or OAuth). When you do res.render, it will get the template as HTML string, but will not be showed in the browser automatically

Comment: @borislemke yes i was thinkin about that, but how i should tell  to my server to render the other page ?

Comment: can u post your full html code

Comment: Which part you want ? Because all the interesting parts are in the posts ^^